# Showing a series is not the Fourier series of a Riemann integrable function.

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

> I want to show that the series
> $\sum_1^\infty \frac{\sin(nx)}{\sqrt{n}}$ is not the Fourier series of a Riemann integrable function on $[-\pi,\pi]$.

I was going to do this by showing that the partial Fourier sums of $f$ do not converge to $f$ in $L^2 [-\pi,\pi]$ as $n\to \infty$.

So I was going about it like this:
$\int_{-\pi}^\pi|\sum_1^\infty \frac{\sin(nx)}{\sqrt{n}}-\sum_1^m \frac{\sin(nx)}{\sqrt{n}}|^2dx=\int_{-\pi}^\pi|\sum_{m+1}^\infty \frac{\sin(nx)}{\sqrt{n}}|^2 dx
$

I want to show that this goes to infinity but I am struggling with how to go further. I was also wondering if I was correct in just allowing the function to be the Fourier series.
Any help would be much appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: Well maybe it's just an error of typing, but your sum at the end of the calculus is not from 1 to m+1 but from m+1 to $+\infty$ for a start. 
Now maybe I would deal with this differently: Let f be this function. I would try to calculate its fourier coefficients, I think you will be able to change the order of the sum sign and integral sign, and see if you will indeed find 0 for the cos and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ for the sin. Because if f is riemann integrable you will find this, and if not you will get a contradiction

Comment: Thankyou for that, just fixed it up. In regards to your response, the function is arbitrary, so I can't simply calculate its fourier series. I think the way i'm going about it is right, based on the theorems we have learnt, however I'm just not too sure about going further.

Comment: Actually f is not arbitrary since you have an explicit formula that defines it:
 f(x) = $ \sum_1^\infty \frac{sin(nx)}{\sqrt{n}} $ 
The thing is, if this is a fourier series of a riemann integrable function, theorems regarding this field tells you that f must be equal to its Fourier development, if I remember correctly. I think this is called Dirichlet's conditions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_conditions
Now once you have this, you can perfectly well calculate its fourier coefficient, and look for the contradiction. I'm not saying it's the only solution though..

Comment: I'll try to see if this is good enough to answer your question

Comment: You could show that [Bessel's Inequality](http://www.sosmath.com/fourier/fourier4/fourier4.html) would not hold.

Comment: Hi david, yeah I don't mind that idea, although the problem im having with that is the same one im having above. Firstly would i assume f(x)=$\sum_1^\infty \frac{sin(nx)}{\sqrt{n}}$. Secondly, how would i go simplifying the expression $\int_{-\pi}^\pi|\sum_1^\infty \frac{sin(nx)}{\sqrt{n}}|^2 dx
$?

Comment: If you assume $f$ is Riemann integrable and is represented by your series, then the right hand side of Bessel's inequality is finite by assumption (since $f^2$ would be Riemann integrable), but the left hand side, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/(\sqrt n)^2$, is infinite. (So, no need to evaluate the integral; you're assuming it's finite.)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose it was the Fourier series of some Riemann integrable function $f$. Then $f$ would also be $L^2$, and so the Fourier coefficients $\left\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^+}$ would be square summable by Parseval's formula. But square summing this sequence gives us the harmonic series, which diverges, and hence it cannot be the Fourier series of some Riemann integrable function.

Comment: Just realized how old this post is lol, this is what happens when people edit really old posts

Answer (score 0):

First of all the series converges for all $x$ in $[-\pi,\pi]$.  Therefore it is the Fourier series of its sum function. It is continuous except at $x = 0$.
Moreover since ${a_n} = \frac{1}{{\sqrt n }}$ is not of *O(1/n)*, (i.e. $n{a_n}$ is not bounded) the Fourier series does not converge boundedly, consequently the sum function is unbounded and hence not Riemann integrable. It is nevertheless Lebesgue integrable.

See Theorem 14 in *Fourier Cosine and Sine Series*.